# angular 4, unable to hide element using ng-if

Tags: angular

I'm using angular 4, I write below code

```
<div ng-if="false">
     <a ng-if="false" routerLink="/login"routerLinkActive="active">Login</a>
</div>
```

but unable to hide div, I even tried ng-show, still no help

Comment: You are looking for `*ngIf`. Don't forget asterisk

Comment: As @yurzui said. Also, please [take a look at the documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) before posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div *ngIf="false">
     <a *ngIf="false" routerLink="/login"routerLinkActive="active">Login</a>
</div>
```

u can also use

```
<div [hidden]="false">
     <a [hidden]="false" routerLink="/login"routerLinkActive="active">Login</a>
</div>
```

Hidden will only apply display:none, ngIf removes the element